# Type `UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter' does not contain a definition for `minSize'

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container, particle-system

> Hello Guys, I'm getting this Error for last 2 days and unable to Solve it ! This is the Error :

```
Assets/ParticleScaler/ParticleScaler.cs(101,12): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter' does not contain a definition for `minSize' and no extension method `minSize' of type `UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

> My Unity Version is 2018.2.18f1 . How can this Error be Fixed ?

> I also tried on Unity 2019, still unable to Solve it.

Comment: Please add your code! .. and well [it doesn't](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/ParticleEmitter.html) so a bit unclear what you are trying .. note btw that `ParticleEmitter` is old .. very old (used previous to Unity Version 3.5) and *obsolete* .. you should probably rather use a `ParticleSystem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UnityEngie.ParticleEmitter became depreciated](https://forum.unity.com/threads/legacy-particle-system-updater.510879/). Replace it with [ParticleSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html).

> 2017.4 and earlier: `ParticleEmitter` will work fully

> 2018.3 and later unity versions: wont work at all - `ParticleEmitter` have been removed from this version.